# Memory Views inside a struct in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

Can memory views be declared inside a struct in cython

I have a memory view defined in a struct as soon as I assign a existing view to that and then try to access either it gives my seg fault.
Here's the code with problem:

```
cdef struct StackRecord:
    int dataLen
    Node *tree_node
    int[::1,:] idx_data
```

Here is a func with prob

```
    cdef buildTree(int[::1,:] ids_data.....) nogil:
        with gil:
            print ids_data[1,0] #prints the data correctly
        cdef stack[StackRecord *] mystack #stack for storing ptr to stackrecord
        cdef StackRecord *stack_rec #stackRecord pointer to be pushed       
        stack_rec.idx_data=ids_data  #line wihth prob iff commented following print work fine else gives segfault
        aho=ids_data
        with gil:
            print ids_data[1,0]
            print aho[1,0]
        mystack.push(stack_rec)
        while loop for tree building:#crashes before this
```

I'm a newbie to cython.Unable to understand what could be the prob.Here the stack used is **c++ library function**.

Comment: You don't define `stack` (but I assume it's the c++ standard library class maybe?). You don't define `stack_rec` which you use in your function. You never use `mystack`, anywhere but I assume it's important...

Comment: @DavidW Added details asked for details.

Comment: this still isn't a minimum complete example. However: I don't think you can use memoryviews is a struct because it's essentially a Python object and so needs a reference counting mechanism which C do (without you doing it explicitly). However the real problem with your code is that you're assigning to an uninitialised pointer, `stack_rec` (so you're trying to write to a completely arbitrary bit of memory)

Comment: @DavidW Any suggestion what I can use instead of memory view for holding data.......is 2d array the last option cause it would be very difficult for me to allocate and initialize every time

Comment: My best suggestion is 1) change from a struct to a cdef class (which can happily store a memoryview) and 2) change from a stack to a Python list. But there may be other issues - you'll have to do much more of the work `with gil` for example

Comment: My application requires nogil most of the time that's why i switch to more of c...i think i will have to bear it....